# How to Pick a period of time instead of specific time ReactNative

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using react-native `Timepicker` to pick a `starting_time`. but instead of `ending_time` i want to pick operation duration time, but it can not be done using timepicker. how can i pick a period of time instead of specific time?

now my app do this:

```
starting_time: 8 am
ending_time: 10 am
```

but what i want is:

```
starting_time: 8am
duration: 2 hours
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be easily doable with a Timepicker so either you use a TimePicker for `starting_time` and a NumberPicker for `duration` **or** you use both TimePickers and you make a calculation to find the duration

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem i fixed it using `Time picker` and `Picker` here is the screen shot.

if this solves your problem i can share the reusable components.

[image: Time Picker]
[image: picker]

Comment: hey! tnx for asnwer, in my case picking time has not any intervals like 30mins. i implemented my own component which user can pick any time he wants.